# Can I use browserlink with an 'html' project?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

I want to create an HTML project that works with browserlink. I created a blank c# project and set it to type 'class library' so that visual studio stops complaining that there's no 'main' entry point. I created a page index.html and setup a corresponding IIS website.

What do I do now? I can't start the project, because it's not a web project. Will this work, or do I need to create something like an MVC project?

Comment: Create a Web Application project instead. If you want to work with standard HTML files, it's probably best to pick a standard ASP.NET application, as you won't have to bother with the whole MVC routing configuration.

Comment: I'm guessing that I just need to add some DLLs and web.config entries to get it to work...

Comment: No the project most be of a specific project type (the .Csproj must have a set box specific guids defined).

Comment: Should that be posted as the answer